# What version of blender for a Mac 10.7.5

Tags: modeling

Which version of Blender should I download for my operating system? I have a Mac Pentium processor 10.7.5. I have used blender 2.49 a little in the past a but I need to start using exact measurements and heard that only newer versions than 2.49 have that capability and they were easier to work with. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try the latest version

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! We're glad to have you, but keep in mind that we're a little different. This is not a forum, so you should not think of your question as a forum post or a conversation-starter. It should be a clear, specific question that can be generically applied to other situations that are similar to yours. Have fun!

Comment: ...oh, and please only ask one question per... question. This one can be about "which version" but if you want to know about measurements, you should post a new question. Be warned: do your homework. Measurements have been well discussed already. If you ask a question that's already been answered, your question will be closed as a duplicate. Remember: this isn't a forum. Happy Blending! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Blender can operate on an OSX system of 10.6 or higher. You should be perfectly fine with using your current Mac with the current Blender release!

Alongside Stack Exchange, the official Blender forum and the Blender reddit page are also great resources. For someone starting out, I'd always search these three places for possible answers before asking questions. The Blender Reddit also has a monthly render contest

Answer (score 0):

blender gets updated almost daily.

for exact measurements you can use  [snapping](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html).

You can use the [ruler](https://www.blender.org/manual/interface/ruler_and_protractor.html).

Or you can experiment with this [addon](https://developer.blender.org/T45734) for extra control
https://vimeo.com/137361362

Answer (score 0):

Just be careful of the amount of addons you turn on as it can slow right up especially if using particles and big samples. This Depends on how powerful your mac is of course but you should be able to run the latest on your system no problems.
I have an IMac 3.5ghz 27"5k with 16gig ram.Its nothing special but It does everything I need with blender. I dont have all the addons activated. I made that mistake early on when I was learning.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the latest version.

If you're worried about performance, always use the latest version. The latest version has (almost) always been more efficient.

From [BlenderGuru's post](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/proof-that-cycles-is-getting-faster-speed-comparisons/):

[image]

The latest version (almost) always has the fewest bugs, the most features, the best addon support, and the best community support.

Always use the latest version.

If you're interested in how to do specific measurements in Blender, please ask a separate question.

Comment: gpu cycles rendering on a mac? good one :D

Comment: Lol, fair enough

Answer (score -2):

Just using the most recent version should work.